# Is Horowitz and Sahni's data structure book outdated?

Tags: data-structures, books

I found that Fundamentals of data structures (1982) by Ellis Horowitz and Sartaj Sahni draws my attention naturally, probably because of

- their formal treatment of data structures, and
- their choice of topics and
- their way of organizing the topics into chapters and sections.

But the book was published in early 1980's. I wonder if the topics and the treatment in the book are outdated?

It doesn't seem to have later editions, but only some derivations for specific programming languages.

p.s.: What would you recommend? Thanks.

---

A view of its table of content:

```
Preface 
CONTENTS 
CHAPTER 1 INTRODUCTION 
1.1 Overview 
1.2 SPARKS 
1.3 How to Create Programs 
1.4 How to Analyze Programs 
References and Selected Readings 
Exercises 
CHAPTER 2 ARRAYS 
2.1 Axiomatization 
2.2 Ordered Lists 
2.3 Sparse Matrices 
2.4 Representation of Arrays 
Exercises 
CHAPTER 3 STACKS AND QUEUES 
3.1 Fundamentals 
3.2 A Mazing Problem 
3.3 Evaluation of Expressions 
3.4 Multiple Stacks and Queues 
Exercises 
CHAPTER 4 LINKED LISTS 
4.1 Singly Linked Lists 
4.2 Linked Stacks and Queues 
4.3 The Storage Pool 
4.4 Polynomial Addition 
4.5 More on Linked Lists 
4.6 Equivalence Relations 
4.7 Sparse Matrices 
4.8 Doubly Linked Lists and Dynamic Storage Management 
4.9 Generalized Lists 
4.10 Garbage Collection and Compaction 
4.11 STRINGS - Case Study 
4.11.1 Data Representations for STRINGS 
4.11.2 Pattern Matching in STRINGS 
4.12 Implementing Node Structures 
References and Selected Readings 
Exercises 
CHAPTER 5 TREES 
5.1 Basic Terminology 
5.2 Binary Trees 
5.3 Binary Tree Representations 
5.4 Binary Tree Traversal 
5.5 More on Binary Trees 
5.6 Threaded Binary Trees 
5.7 Binary Tree Representation of Trees 
5.8 Applications of Trees 
5.8.1 Set Representation 
5.8.2 Decision Trees 
5.8.3 Game Trees 
5.9 Counting Binary Trees 
References and Selected Readings 
Exercises 
CHAPTER 6 GRAPHS 
6.1 Terminology and Representations 
6.1.1 Introduction 
6.1.2 Definitions and Terminology 
6.1.3 Graph Representations 
6.2 Traversals, Connected Components and Spanning Trees . . . 
6.3 Shortest Paths and Transitive Closure 
6.4 Activity Networks, Topological Sort and Critical Paths . ... 
6.5 Enumerating All Paths 
References and Selected Readings 
Exercises 
CHAPTER 7 INTERNAL SORTING 
7.1 Searching 
7.2 Insertion Sort 
7.3 Quicksort 
7.4 How Fast Can We Sort? 
7.5 2-Way Merge Sort 
7.6 Heap Sort 
7.7 Sorting on Several Keys 
7.8 Practical Considerations for Internal Sorting 
References and Selected Readings 
Exercises 
CHAPTER 8 EXTERNAL SORTING 
8.1 Storage Devices 
8.1.1 Magnetic Tapes 
8.1.2 Disk Storage 
8.2 Sorting With Disks 
8.2.1 K-Way Merging 
8.2.2 Buffer Handling for Parallel Operation 
8.2.3 Run Generation 
8.3 Sorting with Tapes 
8.3.1 Balanced Merge Sorts 
8.3.2 Polyphase Merge 
8.3.3 Sorting with Fewer Than 3 Tapes 
References and Selected Readings 
Exercises 
CHAPTER 9 SYMBOL TABLES 
9.1 Static Tree Tables 
9.2 Dynamic Tree Tables 
9.3 Hash Tables 
9.3.1 Hashing Functions 
9.3.2 Overflow Handling 
9.3.3 Theoretical Evaluation of Overflow Techniques 
References and Selected Readings 
Exercises 
CHAPTER 10 FILES 
10.1 Files, Queries and Sequential Organizations 
10.2 Index Techniques 
10.2.1 Cylinder-Surface Indexing 
10.2.2 Hashed Indexes 
10.2.3 Tree Indexing -Trees 
10.2.4 Trie Indexing 
10.3 File Organizations 
10.3.1 Sequential Organizations 
10.3.2 Random Organizations 
10.3.3 Linked Organization 
10.3.4 Inverted Files 
10.3.5 Cellular Partitions 
10.4 Storage Management 
References and Selected Readings 
Exercises 
APPENDIX A: SPARKS 
APPENDIX B: ETHICAL CODE IN INFORMATION PROCESSING 
APPENDIX C: ALGORITHM INDEX BY CHAPTER . 
INDEX 562
```

Comment: I removed the (SE-bad) request for an unqualified list of books. The rest of the question is unclear; what does "outdated" mean here? Abstract knowledge does have tendency to retain its value and relevance over time; that said, new knowledge may have been created/found in the meantime. So what's your concern? Have you looked into more recend books and noticed major differences?

Comment: I don't have access to many books. What's your recommendations?

Answer (score 5):

### Yes.

I strongly recommend Pat Morin's more modern textbook *Open Data Structures*, available for free in several dialects at http://opendatastructures.org/.

Comment: "Yes." - how and why is it outdated?

Comment: Seconded. And what does your recommended book do different/better?

Comment: OMG your avatar is *perfect* for the "fascinating" hat!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There was a second edition of this book published in 2007 — [ISBN 0929306406](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0929306406).  So yes, the edition you have is outdated.

Comment: Is the book in 2007 for C++? Is it not a later edition of the book in 1982? Does it inherit all the good things from the  one in 1982?

Comment: There is a C++ edition and another one without C++.  I like the treatment myself and prefer the one without C++.

Comment: @Tim See my edit. It's still sold on Amazon at least.

Comment: @Gilles: thanks. The book's name has "in C" at the end, so I am not sure if it is the second edition of the 1982 edition. I found the toc of the one you linked here http://www.loc.gov/catdir/toc/ecip0714/2007012974.html

Comment: Should I read the one without "in C" in 1982, or the one "in C" in 2007?

Comment: @Gilles: It seems the book in C has first edition here http://lccn.loc.gov/92002524